A question about sending request through UniversalRouter
Recently I'm developing a program in go language, I want to send a request to UniversalRouter (which is provided by Uniswap) with command TRANSFER (command=0x05), the program is simple, and I can transfer ERC20 token without UniversalRouter but it always failed by using the command TRANSFER(0x05) through UniversalRouter. Here is the code to pack parameters in go language:
    // Prepare the command with arguments
    commands := []byte{0x05}

    // The contract address for the ERC20 token from sepolia, it is zero when we want to send ETH instead of token
    tokenAddressBytes := makeBytes(tokenAddress.Bytes(), 32)

    // The address will receive the token/eth
    targetAddressBytes := makeBytes(targetAddress.Bytes(), 32)

    // The amount should be sent to
    valueBytes := makeBytes(value.Bytes(), 32)

    fmt.Printf("transfer value: %d\n", value.Int64())

    // Pack all 3 parameters into 1 byte-array
    argsBytes := make([]byte, 0)

    argsBytes = append(argsBytes, tokenAddressBytes...)
    argsBytes = append(argsBytes, targetAddressBytes...)
    argsBytes = append(argsBytes, valueBytes...)

    inputs := [][]byte{
        argsBytes,
    }


I always got 'execution revert' error with EIP1559, and if I do not use EIP1559, sometimes it says there is no enough fee to pay the gas fee. But the balance in my account is 1.14 ETH which means the tx consumes a lot gas.
BTW: function makeBytes is padding data into 32 bytes (256bit)
Thanks guys for reading this, what did I miss?
